# Put images in two rows inside the slider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a manual slider, in which images should be in two rows - with horizontal sliding. I tried to do it with flexbox but there is something I do wrong...all suggestions welcome

```css
.slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 230px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not restrict it to two rows, scrolls vertically

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 230px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: 0 0 50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="">
</div>
```

use `flex: 0 0 50%`

Comment: thanks, but this is scrolling vertically? I am trying to achieve a horizontal slider, with images always in two rows